# Monkeypatch python's parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Hi everyone,

I am using sympy for research and find myself writing things like `Integer(1) / k` a lot (which, actually, is already a simplification of `Integer(1) / Integer(k)`).

I wonder if there would be a way to "monkeypatch" python's default integer class with the one in sympy, so that I could just write `1 / k`.

I tried overloading `__builtins__.int`, but it does not change what I want, only changes calls like `int(4)` (plus there is a max recursion problem since sympy's `Integer` class uses `int`, but this is different).

Is there a simple way (say, without C code), to change how python parses the code ?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it would be hard to do without breaking everything else. The max recursion problem you saw is the first symptom of this.

May I suggest a simpler approach: Run

```
I = sympy.Integer
```

as the first thing you do in your file/library, and then you can instead call

```
I(1) / k
```

which is a lot easier to write.